# is it possible to retrieve data in the database automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

so far that all i have I use list view to retrieve data first and put it in the designated text boxes,,what i want is that when i retrieve or search data it will automatically put in their designated text boxes in a form

```
private void btnretrieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Information", con);
        SqlDataAdapter dta = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dta.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        lvwcontacts.Items.Clear();

        for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            lvwcontacts.Items.Add(dt.Rows[index]["CONTACT_ID"].ToString());
            lvwcontacts.Items[index].SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[index]["CONTACT_NAME"].ToString());
            lvwcontacts.Items[index].SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[index]["CONTACT_ADDRESS"].ToString());
            lvwcontacts.Items[index].SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[index]["CONTACT_NO"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Aside: consider implementing `using` statements for your connections, commands, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With a `ListView` you won't be able to do that. However, another approach might be something like this:

```
lvwcontacts.Items.AddRange(
    from r in dt.Select()
    select new ListViewItem(r.ItemArray.Cast<string>().ToArray())
);
```

But, you'll also need to change your `SELECT` statement to be:

```
Select CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CONTACT_ADDRESS, CONTACT_NO from Information
```

Comment: I mean I want to retreive data without the use of listview

Comment: @AirlynKheyTalara, you don't use the `ListView` to retrieve data.

Comment: How is that? my codes always need an listview.im trying to not searching without listview

Comment: @AirlynKheyTalara, you want to display the results in something other than a `ListView`?

Comment: I mean If I search the name of a person all information of that person will be display in the form like enrollment form something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the result in a class. First you'll need to create a contact class.

```
Class Contact
{
    '.. containing ID, Name, Address, No
}
```

Then I suggest you pull all of that logic and put it in a function. And In there, instead of populating a list view, you'll populate a list of object.

```
Public List<Contact> GetContacts()
{
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

    con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Information", con);
        SqlDataAdapter dta = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dta.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();


    for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
    {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();

        newContact.ID = dt.Rows[index]["CONTACT_ID"];
        newContact.Name = dt.Rows[index]["CONTACT_NAME"];
        newContact.Address = dt.Rows[index]["CONTACT_ADDRESS"];
        newContact.NO = dt.Rows[index]["CONTACT_NO"];

        contactList.Add(newContact);
    }

    return contactList;
}
```

Then you can put the data from the list anywhere you want.

* I haven't compile the code.

Comment: what if I don't have a class? Is their any way that there is no need for me to create a class?